# Cannot load search template registered with REST API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem when loading a search template which has been registrered through the REST API. If the search template is placed in the /config/scrips/ folder there is no problem.

The template has been registrered via POST to: **/_search/template/templateName**, and I can see that the template has been succesfully registered when I do a GET to: **/_search/template/templateName**.

However, when I try to send a request that utilizes this search template I get an error. If have tried the following endpoints:

`POST: /_search/template` (the one from the documentation)

`POST: [index]/_search/template`

`POST: [index]/[type]/_search/template`

With this body:

```
{
"template": {
"file": "templateName"
},
"params": {
"userId" : "AU43nSoTZOSzwq_2ZUA4",
etc...
}
}
```

But it keeps returning this error:

```
{
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[UDBaJWKqQ5GpZedzLCtrFg][.scripts][0]: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Unable to find on disk script templateName]}]",
"status": 400
}
```

I cannot upload files to the ElasticSearch host that I'm using, so I need to register them via POST request. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct search request is like this:

```
GET /some_index/_search/template
{
  "template": {
    "id":"templateName"
  },
  "params": {
    "userId" : "AU43nSoTZOSzwq_2ZUA4",
    ...
  }
}
```